# How to use a promise as a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I Have an object (myObject). For this object I created a method (objectPromise) which returns a Promise

```
function myObject(){
   this.number = 2;
   this.objectPromise = function(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            if (data == this.number) {
               resolve();
            } else {
               reject();
            }
       });
   };
 };
```

then I have this code **1)**

```
obj = new myObject();
myPromise1
.then(obj.objectPromise)
.then(function(result){

})
.catch(function(err){

});
```

**2)**

```
obj = new myObject();
myPromise1
.then(function(result){
   obj.objectPromise(result)
})
.then(function(result){

})
.catch(function(err){

});
```

I didn't understand why **1)** doesn't call my Promise

Comment: This is quite unclear; `objectPromise` is a function that returns a promise - is that what you intended?  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Did you mean `then(obj.objectPromise)`? Anyways, your code is all over the place. For one, `this.data` doesn't exist. Also, you aren't returning anything to the other `then`s.

Comment: Sorry I made I mistake, yes it returns a promise, but what I didn't understand is that objectPromise wasn't an Object method I wouldn't have to write my code like 2)

Comment: It's an instance method.

Comment: @Li357 I fixed this.data and obj.objectPromise, sorry. what do you mean by it's an instance method ? What's the diference between `.then(obj.objectPromise)` and `.then(function(result) { obj.objectPromise(result) })`

Comment: Methods that use`this` are not "detachable". To specify your method as a .then callback, you need to bind in the method's host object - `.then(obj.method.bind(obj))`. That's JavaScript, regardless of what the method returns, promise or something else.

Comment: @Roamer-1888  thank you that what I wanted to know , i tried it but I noticed if my object is filled during promises chaining I won’t get its value for example : `obj = {}; myPromise1.then(objectPromise.bind(obj))` If I add attributes to obj in myPromise1 I will get an the empty obj passed to objectPromise , do you know why ? Are Promises created statically ?

Comment: Not sure what you might be trying to achieve with `obj = {}; myPromise1.then(objectPromise.bind(obj));`. It's a nonsense because `objectPromise` doesn't exist except as a property of instances of `myObject()` and you have introduced a second thing named `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

For **1)**, you are returning the function with this line `.then(obj.objectPromise)`, not the promise itself, so it's actually never called.

Based on the **1)** and **2)**, and if myPromise1 is returning `result`, If I understand the problem correctly, I think you are looking for something more along the lines of:

```
obj = new myObject();
myPromise1
  .then((result) => 
    obj.objectPromise(result)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('objectPromise success code here')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('objectPromise fail code here')
      }))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('myPromise1 fail code here')
  });
```